# Matlab web browser in compiled applications

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment

I've an application written in Matlab that uses the built-in Matlab browser; I do this because I need to be able to use the handle returned from `web` function to read properties of the browser window. This works fine when I just run it in Matlab. However, when I compile the application for distribution, it insists on using the system browser, which I can't read properties from. Does anyone know how to force the use of the Matlab browser in compiled applications?

Alternatively, is there anyway to get a handle for the browser window that is opened?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the Matlab browser is not compiled; instead, the system browser is always used, and there doesn't seem to be a way to detect the close window event directly. However, I found that you can watch the `CurrentLocation` property to the same effect: If you wait for it to be filled, as soon as the window is closed it will be cleared, and you can detect a closed window that way. I've only tried this when the window is closed, not when the application quits, but it works (on Mac, at least).